# My Java Swing drawing tool can't be runned

Tags: java, swing

So, I made my first useful app - a paint and drawing tool, but... It can't be runned (started). I don't know, is the problem in my computer or in the code... Here is the code:

```
    package MaddpawNightpainter;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Nightpainter2 {

      JButton clearBtn, blackBtn, blueBtn, greenBtn, redBtn, magentaBtn;
      Nightpainter drawArea;
      ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (e.getSource() == clearBtn) {
            drawArea.clear();
          } else if (e.getSource() == blackBtn) {
            drawArea.black();
          } else if (e.getSource() == blueBtn) {
            drawArea.blue();
          } else if (e.getSource() == greenBtn) {
            drawArea.green();
          } else if (e.getSource() == redBtn) {
            drawArea.red();
          } else if (e.getSource() == magentaBtn) {
            drawArea.magenta();
          }
        }
      };

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Nightpainter().show();
      }


  public void show() {
    // create main frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nightpainter 1.0");
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    // set layout on content pane
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // create draw area
    drawArea = new Nightpainter();

    // add to content pane
    content.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // create controls to apply colors and call clear feature
    JPanel controls = new JPanel();

    clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");
    clearBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    blackBtn = new JButton("Black");
    blackBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    blueBtn = new JButton("Blue");
    blueBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    greenBtn = new JButton("Green");
    greenBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    redBtn = new JButton("Red");
    redBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    magentaBtn = new JButton("Magenta");
    magentaBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);

    // add to panel
    controls.add(greenBtn);
    controls.add(blueBtn);
    controls.add(blackBtn);
    controls.add(redBtn);
    controls.add(magentaBtn);
    controls.add(clearBtn);

    // add to content pane
    content.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    // can close frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // show the swing paint result
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // :)
  }

}
```

And the other file:

```
package MaddpawNightpainter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/*

Author: Bogdan Ganev

Title: Maddpaw Nightpainter

Description: Nightpainter is a drawing tool, part of Maddpaw - Multifunctional App for Designers,
Developers And Writers

Copyright: Copyright (C) 2016 Bogdan Ganev. All rights reserved. Maddpaw, Multifunctional App for Designers,
Developers And Writers is a trademark of Bogdan Ganev. Java TM is a trademark of Oracle Corporation (R) 

*/
public class Nightpainter extends JComponent {

  // Image in which we're going to draw
  private Image image;
  // Graphics2D object ==> used to draw on
  private Graphics2D g2;
  // Mouse coordinates
  private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

  public Nightpainter() {
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
        oldX = e.getX();
        oldY = e.getY();
      }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // coord x,y when drag mouse
        currentX = e.getX();
        currentY = e.getY();

        if (g2 != null) {
          // draw line if g2 context not null
          g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
          // refresh draw area to repaint
          repaint();
          // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
          oldX = currentX;
          oldY = currentY;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
      // image to draw null ==> we create
      image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
      g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
      // enable antialiasing
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      // clear draw area
      clear();
    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  }

  // now we create exposed methods
  public void clear() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.white);
    // draw white on entire draw area to clear
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
  }

  public void red() {
    // apply red color on g2 context
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
  }

  public void black() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
  }

  public void magenta() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.magenta);
  }

  public void green() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.green);
  }

  public void blue() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
  }

}
```

So is the problem in my computer or in the code? By the way, it's 10,3 KB...

Comment: "Can't be runned" how? How are you trying to run it, and do you get any exceptions or error messages?

Comment: You need a top-level component `JFrame` or `JDialog` to place your component. See more swing tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in the NightPainter2 class to this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Nightpainter2 {

  static JButton clearBtn, blackBtn, blueBtn, greenBtn, redBtn, magentaBtn;
  static Nightpainter drawArea;
  static ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == clearBtn) {
        drawArea.clear();
      } else if (e.getSource() == blackBtn) {
        drawArea.black();
      } else if (e.getSource() == blueBtn) {
        drawArea.blue();
      } else if (e.getSource() == greenBtn) {
        drawArea.green();
      } else if (e.getSource() == redBtn) {
        drawArea.red();
      } else if (e.getSource() == magentaBtn) {
        drawArea.magenta();
      }
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create main frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nightpainter 1.0");
        // set layout on content pane
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // create draw area
        drawArea = new Nightpainter();

        // add to content pane
        frame.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // create controls to apply colors and call clear feature
        JPanel controls = new JPanel();

        clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");
        clearBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        blackBtn = new JButton("Black");
        blackBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        blueBtn = new JButton("Blue");
        blueBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        greenBtn = new JButton("Green");
        greenBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        redBtn = new JButton("Red");
        redBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        magentaBtn = new JButton("Magenta");
        magentaBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);

        // add to panel
        controls.add(greenBtn);
        controls.add(blueBtn);
        controls.add(blackBtn);
        controls.add(redBtn);
        controls.add(magentaBtn);
        controls.add(clearBtn);

        // add to content pane
        frame.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        // can close frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // show the swing paint result
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // :)
  }
```

I don't know why it worked, I just saw a line through 'show' in new NightPainter2.show(); so tried this. Didn't expect it to work, honestly :)

And you may want to add frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); to make it open in the center of the screen.

Comment: Can you select it as the best answer please? I've just started out and need the reputation :) It's the least you could do :)

Comment: The reason this change works is because in the original code the JFrame you created was a local variable to the show() method and when that method returned the JFrame would be garbage collected.  This rewrite keeps the JFrame alive because it doesn't go out of scope until the main() returns.